# Selenium/Ruby unknown driver, firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a selenium test that I have working in chrome, I'm trying to get selenium to run the test in every browser. When I try and access firefox I get an error though.

Code up to the error...

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :Firefox
```

I get the following error on the line where driver is declared...

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:49:in 'for': unknown driver: :Firefox (ArgumentError)
from /Users/samuelowens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in 'for'
from test.rb:47:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why that might be and how to fix it? Is there an easy way to write a selenium test and check it in multiple browsers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not capital case `Firefox` but `firefox`

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

Comment: too easy! :D  @sam, accept his answer if this solves your issue